# key password and keystore password using ikeyman tool

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, websphere, keystore

Can you please advise if key password and keystore password using ikeyman tool are they same or different because ikeyman tool ask only keystore password?Help please..
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ikeyman uses 1 passphrase to encrypt the keystore (container) and its contents. There is no ability to protect the individual private keys with a separate passphrase. Contrast with openssl pkcs12 handling -- the entire keystore can have one password, and each RSA key inside can have a separate passphrase.

Comment: Okay.So I have setup a JKS using ikeyman tool and for the TLS configuration in the API application, it has fields for keystore password and key password.In my case shall I enter the same?

Comment: As per this link, I'm configuiring in my application.Just that I have not used keytool and used ikeyman tool to generate the JKS, hence I dont have any explicit key password for the JKS.So shall I enter the same here?https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/tls-configuration

Comment: Could  you please advise or if we can add a keypassword to the existing JKS?

Comment: There is no keypassword in Ikeyman. The keystore itself is password protected.